# Could not find method group() for arguments [ros.rosjava_core]

Tags: ros, rosjava-core, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

### I'm trying to install the rosjava_core with the "gradle install", but I'm getting the next error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/home/user/my_workspace/rosjava_core/build.gradle' line: 22
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'rosjava_core'.
  Cause: Could not find method group() for arguments [ros.rosjava_core] on root project 'rosjava_core'
  --

In the build.gradle I have it:
...
allprojects {
group 'ros.rosjava_core'
version = '0.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
...

How should I configure that file? Any suggestion?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33547/could-not-find-method-group()-for-arguments-%5Bros.rosjava_core%5D/) by [santidoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2338/santidoo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-05-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you're using the wrong version of gradle? You should execute the gradle wrapper (rosjava_core/gradlew). You should not need to modify rosjava_core/build.gradle.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0